# Keep vuetify element on top when scrolling

Tags: vuetify.js

With Vuetify 2.0, I've got a layout with two cards - one on top of the other.

The bottom card is large so the user must scroll.
I want the top card to stay in view (not be scrolled out of view), as it is used to display information about what I select in the bottom card.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why this didn't work before, but creating a class like this, seems to do the trick:

```
.sticky {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

Credit where it's due: [This is where I found it](https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526)

*If anyone knows the "Vuetify way" of doing it, please share.*